# Merge TileCache Layers

Tags: openlayers, tilecache

I have a TileCache server with this configuration:

```
[cache]
type=Disk
base=/var/maps/cache

[osm]
type=Mapnik
mapfile=/var/maps/bin/mapnik/osm.xml
bbox=-180.0,-90,180.0,90
srs=EPSG:4326

[oge]
type=MapServerLayer
mapfile=/var/maps/defs/OGE.map
layers=OGETransLines
```

I am using OpenLayers to show the data and currently I have requesting the 'osm' layer with an OpenLayers.Layer.TMS object and the 'oge' layer with an OpenLayers.Layer.WMS object. Is there a way to merge the two together and request them at the same time? So far I have only been able to get the 'osm' layer with TMS.

**EDIT:** My Javascript to make things clearer:

```
map = new OpenLayers.Map("mapDiv",
                                  {
                                      projection: epsg4326,
                                      maxResolution: 360 / 512
                                  });

        baseLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.TMS("TarigmaOSM",
                                              "http://1.1.1.1/cgi-bin/tilecache/tilecache.cgi/",
                                              {
                                                  serviceVersion: "1.0.0",
                                                  layername: "osm",
                                                  type: "png",
                                                  attribution: "Data CC-by-SA OpenStreetMap"
                                              });
        map.addLayer(baseLayer);

        overlay = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("Overlay",
                                            "http://1.1.1.1/cgi-bin/tilecache/tilecache.cgi?",
                                            {
                                                layers: "oge",
                                                transparent: "true",
                                                attribution: ""
                                            });
        map.addLayer(overlay);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no way you can do it on the client side. Every layer you create in OpenLayers makes it's own requests to fetch images.

Only possible solution is to create one WMS or TMS service on the server side that reads data from two data sources that you want to merge.

Comment: Any idea how to do that with TileCache? I understand it needs to be on the server side.